# How to manipulate seekbar and textview while text-to-speech is active

Tags: android, android-asynctask, text-to-speech, seekbar

I have a very small example where I want to click a button to change from MainActivity to a different activity (CountDown) that will count down and then return to Main. I want the countdown to be reflected in a TextView while it is spoken out loud. I also want to use a seekbar to control the delay between each countdown. 
I hope I got all the TTS related code correct, i.e. I think I have to do the 'for' loop within the 'onInit' section (or how would I otherwise make sure that the TTS engine is initialized and ready to go ?). I also want to control the delay (currently hardcoded to '2000' in the 'playSilentUtterance' call via the seekbar, but not sure what's the proper way (global variable ?)

This is the code for the 2nd activity:

```
public class CountDown extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    TextView txtCount;
    TextView txtSeekBar;
    SeekBar seekBar;

    private TextToSpeech mTts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_count_up);

        txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
        txtSeekBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSeekBar);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    }

    public void onInit(int i)
    {
        mTts.speak("Starting Countdown", QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        for(int number=5; number>0; number--){

            mTts.speak(number + "", QUEUE_ADD, null);

            mTts.playSilentUtterance(2000, QUEUE_ADD, null);

            txtCount.setText(number+"");
        }

        Intent intent2Training = new Intent(CountDown.this, MainActivity.class);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent2Training);

        while (mTts.isSpeaking()) {
        }

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        txtSeekBar.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + " / " + seekBar.getMax());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried to put the tts stuff into an AsyncTask and now the seekbar works (and I can also update my TextViews, which didn't work before), but now I can't get tts to actually speak. So from the frying pan into the fire ?

Comment: ahh, correction, the AsyncTask was the right way to go, now I can move the seekbar and the textviews are updated in parallel to the speech.  My bad that I commented out required code and forgot to uncomment during the debug frenzy ...